# Is it possible iterate values of an ArrayList as a tooltip in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, data-structures

I have a list with 10 values.I want to iterate all these values in a tool tip.How do I do it in Swing?

Comment: Do you mean display them all at once, or display all items in the list in a single tooltip?

Comment: I want to display all items in the list in a single tool tip line by line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My prefered way is to go HTML. Here is how you can acheive what you want and display all lines in one tooltip:

```
String toolTip = "<html>";
for(String line : arrayOfStrings)
{
  toolTip += line +"<br>";
}
toolTip += "</html>";
myComponent.setToolTipText(toolTip);
```

Comment: Consider also an `ul` or `ol` style group of `li` elements (a list).  ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> strList;
//...
StringBuilder items = new StringBuilder();
for(String item : strList) {
    items.append(item + "\n");
}
//...
someJComponentObject.setToolTipText(items.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a string (you can even use html syntax) with the contents of the list and call the setToolTipText() method on the component.

Answer (score 0):

Apache provides a utility in their one of their commons packages called `StringUtils`.  You could use it in the following way:

```
final String itemsString = StringUtils.join(items.toArray());
```

The `itemsString` could then be displayed in the 'tooltip' of your Swing control.

`StringUtils` is a part of [Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/lang/), (see [documentation here](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html)).

If you use [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/), you can use the following artifact:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Where can I get this utility?

Comment: Updated my comment to include a link to the library & the Maven dependency.

Comment: Shouldn't that be [StringUtils.join()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.String%29)?